# Using CheckBoxFor in a loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I use  Html.CheckBoxFor in a loop? If so how?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. (This is using spark, but the question still applies to razor or aspx)

```
<ul class="voteOptions">
    <for each="var answer in poll.Answers">
        <li>!{Html.LabelFor(a =>a.Answer)}</li>
        <li>!{Html.CheckBoxFor(a =>a.Key)}</li>
    </for>
 </ul>
```

This obviously doesn't work because `a` represents the viewmodel not the current item in the loop.

Comment: Are you encountering some problems with this? If yes could you describe them in more details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use EditorFor inside a foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983999/how-to-use-editorfor-inside-a-foreach)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<for each="var answer in poll.Answers">
    <li>!{Html.LabelFor(a => answer.Answer)}</li>
    <li>!{Html.CheckBoxFor(a => answe.Key)}</li>
</for>
```

But obviously a better solution is to never write any loops but use editor templates as in this case your code will become:

```
<ul class="voteOptions">
    !{Html.EditorFor(x => x.Answers)}
</ul>
```

Comment: I take your point for the regarding editor template. How is the first part of your answer different to mine?

Comment: @Dan, `a => answer.Answer` where `answer` is the variable you have defined in the loop. Not sure if it is the proper syntax though as I am not familiar with Spark.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like doing it this way, but it works if you have to use Html.XXXFor

1: Create a property on your model called CurrentAnswer (type Answer)

2: In your loop set answer to CurrentAnswer

3: then call Html.XXXFor(a => a.CurrentAnswer)