# c# MVC3 Binding IEnumerable Model to table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a university project and trying to learn MVC3 at the same time.  I have a shopping basket style page with a table that shows the items.  The model contains a list of products purchased.

I can display the products in a table via looping through the Model and displaying, however I need to implement a way to update the quantities.  I currently have the quantities displayed in a HTML.TextBox which can be amended, but when I change the value it's not represented as such in the model.

Could somebody please advise how I could do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a view-model layer?

Comment: I have a controller, and then some Models that are standard data objects.  The functionality is done via a WCF layer.

Answer (score 0):

To update the model, you have post the edited values back to the server. To populate the model values in a text box, you can use the Html.EditorFor extension method and Pass in the lambda expression pointing to the quantity property. You can put the shopping cart controls within an HTML form control with an action of "post" and target of the controller route which will update the model. These are very basic operations in Asp.Net MVC, and you should be able to see how it is done in [www.asp.net/MVC](http://Www.asp.net/mvc)

**Please do some research before posting your questions in the forum.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the condescension ;)  I know how to do this with a single item model.  But you cannot do the EditorFor when looping through a collection.  My question is specifically for working with an IEnumerable object passed via the model.

Comment: You would use the `code`foreach`code` construct to loop through the Model, and then paint each item as you would a single item model. Here is an example of how you would do it using the razor syntax [link](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax).

Comment: Why can't you use an EditorFor inside a foreach loop? It should work. Here is a related question on that topic in Stackoverflow. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983999/how-to-use-editorfor-inside-a-foreach)