# Building dynamic view based on Fields returned from DataBase in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to render view at runtime based on fields returned from Database. Any help should be appreciated, for designing the prototype / approach

I have below model,

```
public class DynamicFields
{
    public string propertyName { get; set; }
    public string propertyType { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller, it will be `List<DynamicFields>`

So based on propertyType, i have to render the control like TextBox/DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create EditorTemplates for every value of `propertyType`

_textInput.cshtml (assuming textInput is a possible value of `propertyType`)

```cs
@model DynamicFields
@Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.propertyName)
```

_dateTimeInput.cshtml (assuming dateTimeInput is a possible value of `propertyType`)

```cs
@model DynamicFields
@Html.TextBoxFor(item => Model.propertyName, new {class = "datetime"})
```

the view:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<DynamicFields>

@foreach(var field in Model){
    @Html.LabelFor(model => field.propertyName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => field.propertyName, field.propertyType) @*tell razor which template to use *@

}
```

more information can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407414(v=vs.118).aspx

updated my answer considering the foreach loop with knowledge from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987585/690178

Comment: Thank you very much. If i Use this approach, Can I pass data to controller on button click.

Comment: @Html.LabelFor(item =>  item.propertyName)

Does not contain definition for "PropertyType" and no extension method for PropertyType accepting first argument.

Can you please help me on this error?

Comment: in my code 'field' is correct, not item (see the foreach loop: '@foreach(var field in Model){' )

and yes, passing data to a controller is called submitting a form.

Comment: I am using item variable in foreach loop. Anyhow I replaced with field but still same error.

Comment: C# is case-sensitive. propertyType != PropertyType. Please don't use the comments to ask new questions. Comments don't show up in search results. I corrected my answer btw. Please excuse me for other minor mistakes. This is written out of the blue and it is 12.15am where I live :'). The code should point you in the right direction though.