# How to pass mutiple textbox values using checkbox from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a edit form where I Have two textboxes and  checkbox. I am trying to update book details using checkbox. I am not sure how to pass the textbox values from view to controller using checkbox in Entity Framework. I need to save save those edited textbox box values in DB. Right now my checkboxex are not passing the edit textbox values to controller.

My Edit form looks like this
[Edit Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tthsD.png)

View :

```html
@if (Model.Count > 0)
        {
            <div>
                @foreach (var books in Model)
                {
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => books.caption)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => books.caption)
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => books.copies)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => photos.copies)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="@books.id" name="id" />
                        </div>
               }
          </div>
}

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="UPDATE" />
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="ADD"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="DELETE" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Contoller :

```
public ActionResult EditBooks(int id, IEnumerable<int> id, string submitButton, 
                            [Bind(Include ="id,caption,copies")] Books books)
```

{

```
     switch (submitButton)

    {  
         case: UPDATE

         if (ModelState.IsValid)

          {

             try

            {

                foreach (var item in id)
                {
                    var update = _db.Books.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == item);

                    if (update != null)
                    {
                        _db.MyTable.Add(update);
                        _db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id});
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

}

I am not sure my controller code is right.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983999/how-to-use-editorfor-inside-a-foreach)

Comment: My checkbox is not passing the edited textbox values to controller.

Comment: In addition to the linked question above, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964553/mvc-form-not-able-to-post-list-of-objects) states the problem even more clearly.